# How to tell the difference between Lesser and Great spotted Woodpeckers?

Tags: birds, uk, bird-behaviour, bird-identification

Around my work I walk in local parks for a couple of hours a day, and I've noticed we have Green Woodpeckers, and I've seen them quite a few times and can now recognise them rather easily.

Recently I have seen Spotted Woodpeckers, I assumed it was a Great Spotted Woodpecker, however recently learnt we have Lesser Spotted Woodpeckers in the UK as well. It was pouring with rain at the time so I was unable to get a very close look at the pair. How would you tell the difference between Great and Lesser Spotted Woodpeckers by their look and behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Size:

The great spotted is greater in size than the lesser spotted. Perhaps that goes without saying but the difference is quite significant. The great spotted is about the size of a blackbird. The lesser spotted is about the size of a sparrow.

#### Red:

Female lessers have a white cap. Male lessers have a red cap, juvenile greats have a red cap but they're bigger than lessers.

Greats have a red bum and males have a red patch on the back of the head. They also have larger white patches on the wings.

#### In summary

It's really hard to tell the difference, be glad we don't also get the middle spotted woodpecker. The chances are you saw a great spotted wookpecker because the lesser spotted is quite rare.

https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/wildlife-guides/bird-a-z/lesser-spotted-woodpecker/

https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/wildlife-guides/bird-a-z/great-spotted-woodpecker/

Comment: From this I'd imagine they were Greater then, as they were much larger than a sparrow!